# Can i connect redux-form [v6] to other state, like in [v5]?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

Can i configure `mapStateToProps` and other react-redux parameters in **redux-form `v6`**.

Like this in **redux-form `v5`** ~> https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSZKM.jpg

> ```
> reduxForm(config:Object, mapStateToProps?, mapDispatchToProps?, mergeProps?, options?)
> ```
>
> Creates a decorator with which you use redux-form to connect your form component to Redux. It takes a config parameter and then optionally mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps and options parameters which correspond exactly to the parameters taken by react-redux's connect() function, allowing you to connect your form component to other state in Redux.

.

For example:

```
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';

...

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signUp'
}, state => ({
  lists: state.get('list').toJS()
}));
```

Comment: Could you please add the example from the image as text in your question? It makes it searchable and easier to answer.

Comment: Added example as text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can connect your redux state to your redux-form component in version 6. Here is an example (You have to decorate connect manually now).

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import {
    actionCreatorOne,
    actionCreatorTwo
} from './actionCreators';

class MyForm...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        name: state.user.name
    };
}

let mapDispatch = {
    actionCreatorOne,
    actionCreatorTwo
};

MyForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm'
})(MyForm);

export default MyForm = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatch)(MyForm);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i know about this way, but i ask about old way same as in [v5]. In [v5] way more convenient.

Comment: Oh I see, you were looking for a way for them to handle the connect functionality for you :) Yeah, I was in the same boat yesterday.